# NSInvalidArgumentException in GPPSignIn addSavedKeychainName

Tags: ios, google-plus

After putting Google+ login onto my iOS app, I started seeing this error in crashlytics about 5-10 times per day.

Fatal Exception NSInvalidArgumentException
*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil

It happens in this method:
-[GPPSignIn addSavedKeychainName:] + 126

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I followed the instructions on google's developer site to implement the feature: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?